# Jenkins/hudson email-ext plugin - "committers" option not visible

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I'm trying to use the **Jenkins email-ext plugin** (*Editable Email Notification*) to notify a committer if they've broken a build.

This can apparently be done by adding a post build action to a project, choosing "Editable Email Notification", and then selecting a committers checkbox.... but I can't seem to find this checkbox!

If you look at my screenshot below you can see that there is no option for just committers, and I can only see "Recipient list", "Developers", or "Requestor", and only when I add an extra trigger.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get this option?  Am I missing another plugin that is required (I've got the Subversion Plug-in) or something?

Email ext plugin is v2.32 (the latest) and Jenkins is v1.528 (nearly the latest).

[image: Jenkins email-ext plugin]

Answer (score 1):

There is no option as "committers" we have only the option to chose between developers or to opt for a trigger for success or failure to a requestors or to list of people in the recipients list